# Criar um texto de Score .txt sem sobrescrever o arquivo

Tags: c#

O comando escrito abaixo não cria o texto de score .txt no diretório da pasta onde está instalado o joguinho eu também precisava que o código abaixo não sobrescrevesse o arquivo mas adicionar a pontuação embaixo dos pontos já gravados. C# Visual Studio Community 2017.

```
varexe = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;


StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(varexe + "\\Score.txt");
                                                                    writer.WriteLine("Player1");
                                                                    writer.WriteLine(tent);
                                                                    writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um comando File.AppendText, aqui você encontra como usa-lo: [Append Text C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**Código copiado do site que recomendei**

Você escolhe entre:

(1) Escrever no arquivo

(2) Adicionar ao arquivo

(3) Só ler o arquivo

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;

class Test 
 {
   public static void Main() 
   {

     string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
     // texto entra uma vez só no arquivo
     if (!File.Exists(path)) 
       {
        //(1) Criando o arquivo e escrevendo nele (Só de exemplo)
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
         {
            sw.WriteLine("Player1");
            sw.WriteLine("Pontos");
            sw.WriteLine("blablabla");
        }   
    }

    //(2) Aqui adiciona novas informações no texto no final da linha.
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
            sw.WriteLine("Player1");
            sw.WriteLine("Pontos");
            sw.WriteLine("blablabla");
    }   

    //(3) Aqui abre o arquivo apenas para leitura
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
    {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Espero ter te ajudado!